# How to clear indexedDB using localforage.js when upgrade needed due to version

Tags: indexeddb, localforage

I'm working on a project using `localforage.js` for data caching in indexedDB.
Data is always changing, so I need to clear data which is old version in browser's indexedDB.

I guessed that `localforage.config({ version })` would be a solution, but it didn't clear old versioned data. The structure of data is not same between new version and old version, so my app goes to crash.

If it's not localforage but plain indexedDB api, there's `onupgradeneed` event handler function that I can control, I can clear old version data manually.

But it's `localforage.js` on my project, I can't control this event handler, so I'm figuring out how to do it.

Thanks in advance, I hope to find the solution soon..!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a good idea is to add your app verion to each key in the stored data:

```
localforage.setItem(`data_${APP_VERSION}`, data)
```